# Get line break in FXLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am using `FXLabel` & I want the indexes or characters where the line is break(new line). 
Also I want the number of lines in the `FXLabel`. I googled it but not get any luck.
How it is possible?

Comment: did you try with \n and \r ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I had tried with both \n & \r but still it does not returns me the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the method used internally by FXLabel? It's a private method that FXLabel declares as a category on NSString, but you can expose it in your code by declaring it in another category, like this:

```
@interface NSString (FXLabel_Private)

- (NSArray *)FXLabel_linesWithFont:(UIFont *)font
                 constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
                     lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
                       lineSpacing:(CGFloat)lineSpacing
                  characterSpacing:(CGFloat)characterSpacing
                      kerningTable:(NSDictionary *)kerningTable
                      allowOrphans:(BOOL)allowOrphans

@end
```

Then you can call that method on your label string and pass in parameters that match your label settings. It returns an array containing each line of the string.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the above method, so that I can implement it in my app.

Comment: You just call [@"my label string" FXLabel_linesWithFont:myLabelFont ...] ect and it will return an array of strings that match the lines that the FXLabel will draw.